# jquery: prevent form submit on ajax validation error

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with some ajax validation fields.(not all fields are validated using ajax)

I want to prevent form submit if there is an error on one of those fields.

I would like it to be generic for other forms I have with ajax validation.

1 flag would not do the trick.

This is what the ajax field looks like on error:

```
<label id="id_name_lab" class="error">name</label>
<input id="id_name" type="text" maxlength="128" name="name">
<label id="id_name_succ_icn" class="icon_succ" style="display: none;"></label>
<label id="id_name_load_icn" class="icon_load" style="display: none;"></label>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "error on one of those fields" is

Comment: I edited my answer.
I need to go over form fields and look for class error and id the contains load_icn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my idea is using callback-chains.

**Pseudo code**

```
$("form").one( "submit", function() {
    var self = this;

    // ajax validation
    $.ajax( /* ... */ )
        .done( function() {
            // call validation, if form is valid, ajaxValidation calls submit again.
            ajaxValidation( self );
        });

    // first submit is always ignored.
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

function ajaxValidation( target ) {
    // check valid & call submit
}
```

and it need bind submit handler above, when you want.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery:

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
 });
```

Without jquery:

```
return false;
```

On the onsubmit element of your form.

Comment: You did not take into considering error on the ajax validated fields

Comment: Just write your validation if(myfield == '') return false; else [submit my form] with your own rules that are needed.

Comment: I don't want to specify field name, i want it to be generic